# Android ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have two activities, both of which use a listview.  I called one "android:list", but called the second one "@+id/myList".  Now, my application crashes on startup with a "must have android:list" error message.  How does one get around this?

Comment: Can you show the exception (logcat) and the XML layout(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your activity must be extended from `ListActivity`, so you should create a `listview` with the tag `android:name="android:id/list"` in the layout xml. Hopes useful to you!

Answer (score 2):

If your Activity's extend ListActivity, then your ListViews must have an ID of android:list.  If they are two separate Activity's then it is OK for both to have a ListView with the same ID - the important thing is not to have two Views with the same ID in the same Layout.

Answer (score 1):

[ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) looks for a ListView with the ID `android.R.id.list` to get a reference so it can provide all the API features for the developer. Without that it thinks there's no list and crashes when trying to use it. Just define the list in xml like you do with the other one and it will start working. All the pieces need to fit together like a jigsaw puzzle.